# SQL Selection not outputting data

Tags: php, mysql

Starting off, I'm kind of stumbling in the dark here with PHP/SQL, and don't really know how to bugtest that well, so forgive my vagueness about the exact nature of the problem. Moving on.

I have some code which grabs category ids, names, and descriptions from an SQL table, and saves the result to a variable. This is done through statement preparing to avoid an possibility of SQL injection. This value is then fed into some PHP which checks if the query had any response, and if so prints that into a table.

```
<?php

//create_cat.php
include_once (__DIR__ . '/../includes/db_connect.php');
include_once (__DIR__ . '/../includes/functions.php');

include_once (__DIR__ . '/header.php');
ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);
$stmt = "SELECT
            cat_id,
            cat_name,
            cat_description
        FROM
            categories";
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    if(!$result = $mysqli->query($stmt)){
        echo 'The categories could not be displayed, please try again later.';
    } else {
        if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
            echo 'No categories defined yet.';
        } else {
            //prepare the table
            echo '<table border="1">
              <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Last topic</th>
              </tr>';

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td class="leftpart">';
                echo '<h3><a href="category.php?id">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</a></h3>' . $row['cat_description'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td class="rightpart">';
                echo '<a href="topic.php?id=">Topic subject</a> at 10-10';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo <<<error
    <p>
    <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="../index.php">login</a>.
    </p>
error;
}
include_once (__DIR__ . '/footer.php');
?>
```

However, the table SQL table definitely has values, but the PHP is only outputting: "The categories could not be displayed, please try again later."

Comment: Add the following lines to the top of your PHP code, they should help you debug the problem: `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Also see the documentation for `store_result()` [here](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php) because you should be storing the value into a variable and then analyzing the variable. There seems to be some confusion in your statements. Refer [here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) for a tutorial on using mysqli.

Comment: Your code is mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions. Don't do that. Use `mysqli_` functions only.

Comment: Do you think using `prepare()` is necessary at this point? This command isn't inserting anything into my DB, and all DB inputs are already sanitized.

Comment: @spencer7593, fixed. I replaced the `mysql_num_rows($result) == 0` with `$result->num_rows === 0` and `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` with `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Where is your statement?

Comment: The statement is `$prep_stmt = "SELECT
            cat_id,
            cat_name,
            cat_description,
        FROM
            categories";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);`

Comment: @Tim3880 Though I'm not sure about using `$mysqli->prepare()`, is that a necessary precaution for this kind of operation? Should I just set $stmt as the statement directly and then use $stmt in `$db->query($stmt)`?

Comment: Your statement has an extra comma before from

Comment: @Tim3880 Thanks! That fixed it mostly, I'm no longer getting any error codes. I also just removed the $stmt_prep command, I think I only need that when entering data into the sql db. However, now it just prints nothing to the page. -_-

Comment: Ok, I updated the post to the code currently running.

Comment: did you run the statement directly from sqladmin? i can't comment on your php code since i don't use it, but it seems missing something.

Comment: Ok, figured it out, the table is just being shoved under the footer. Now it's just fixing crappy html echos. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it working. I removed $stmt_prep commands, made sure to only use mysqli commands, and fixed some syntax errors. Code still has broken HTML, but the problem I was asking about is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep the object oriented style, the main mistake was closing the statement before fetching the results. PHP will free up the statement at the end of the script anyway, but once you've called `$stmt->close();` you won't be able to read any data from the query. Since PHP does copy by reference, `$result = $stmt;` doesn't copy the data, it just references the same closed statement.

The fetch syntax also isn't quite what you had: you need to bind some placeholder variables with eg `$stmt->bind_result($name, $description);` and then call `$stmt->fetch()` instead of fetch_assoc.

I'm not clear exactly what `login_check` does but it would seem to me that you'd want to put this check earlier so that the query is not executed if the user is unauthorized.

Your original code would end up looking something like:

```
<?php

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
            echo 'No categories defined yet.';
        } else {
            //prepare the table
            echo '<table border="1">
              <tr>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Last topic</th>
              </tr>';

            $stmt->bind_result($name, $description);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td class="leftpart">';
                echo '<h3><a href="category.php?id">' . $name . '</a></h3>'
                  . $description;
                echo '</td>';
                echo '<td class="rightpart">';
                echo '<a href="topic.php?id=">Topic subject</a> at 10-10';
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'The categories could not be displayed, please try again later.';
    }
} else {
    echo <<<error

    <p>
        <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please 
        <a href="../index.php">login</a>.

     </p>
error;
}
```